# AngularJS, how to pass API key to service in order to authenticate?

Tags: ajax, json, angularjs

First, this is my service that retrieves a promise for an API key:

```
app.factory('AuthenticationService', function($http) {
        return {
        getData: function() {
            return $http.get('http://game.mywebsite.com/start/?token=2132')
                .then(function(result) {
                    return result.data;
            }
        );
    }
}
```

In my controller I bind the key:

```
AuthenticationService.getData()
    .then(function(result) {
        $scope.apiKey = result;            
});
```

I was wondering where to pass an API key which I retrieved from the server. I have a controller implementation:

```
 DrawService.getData($scope.apiKey)
    .then(function(result) {
        $scope.numbers = result.data;
});
```

And the service:

```
app.factory('DrawService', function($http) {
        return {
            getData: function(apiKey) {
            return $http.get('http://game.mywebsite.com/draw/')
                .then(function(result) {
                    return result.data;
        });
    }
}
```

And still I am not authorized to access data from the server. I was wondering where to pass this apiKey parameter in order to be authorized, considering I have more services which should return some data, but require authorization first?

Comment: Is your API key is header of request, or this needs to be a parameter?

Comment: It needs to be a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

bltzrrr, is game.mywebsite an application of yours?

If so, you need to know the param name in order to request it right.

Supposing it is apiKey, it'd look like:

`$http.get('http://game.mywebsite.com/draw/', {params: {apiKey: 'apiKey'}});`

Hope this is going to help you

Comment: Yes, it is. And on the server side, there is absolutely no clue for where I should pass this API key. I have tried your solution but I am still unauthorized.

Comment: bltzrrr, is your service (whether it is Java, Python, etc) receiving any parameters?

Answer (score 0):

its depends on what kind of authorization your server had implemented

Looking at your code i believe you need to pass api token in service headers in order to access data.

you can pass data in to the header of each service

```
 app.factory('DrawService', function($http) {
            return {
                getData: function(apiKey) {
                 return $http.get('http://game.mywebsite.com/draw/',{
                     headers: { "Authorization": "Bearer APIKEY"}
                   }).then(function(result) {
                        return result.data;
                  });
            }
    }
```

Or you can set it globally into header for each and every service call

```
app.factory('DrawService', function($http) {
        return {
            getData: function(apiKey) {
             $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = "Bearer APIKEY";
            return $http.get('http://game.mywebsite.com/draw/')
                .then(function(result) {
                    return result.data;
        });
    }
}
```

Authorization can be bearer,basic or digest.